# How can I use special names as field name in cakephp 3?

Tags: model, cakephp-3.0

I have references field in articles table. When I try to save article entity, cakephp encountered to problem because 'references' is a reserved name in mysql.

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO articles (parent_id, stage_id, stagepart_id, priority, name, tags, body, references, created, modified) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9)
```

How can I use 'references' as a field?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/27859881/1392379**

Comment: Thank you @ndm && Jose Lorenzo :)