# CakePHP 3.1 won't save simple hasMany relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two entities, `Site` and `SitesMetaData` that I want to relate with a hasMany and belongsTo association.

I created everything as per the CakePHP 3.0 book but for some reason it's not generating or saving the association.

Here are my relationships

SitesTable:

```
$this->hasMany('SitesMetaData', [
    'foreignKey' => 'site_id',
    'dependent' => true
]);
```

and SitesMetaDataTable (auto generated by baking the model):

```
$this->belongsTo('Sites', [
    'foreignKey' => 'site_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Here is my controller function:

```
    $site = $this->Sites->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $site = $this->Sites->patchEntity($site, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['SitesMetaData']]);
        if ($this->Sites->save($site)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The site has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['_name' => 'admin:home']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The site could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

Here is a dump of $this->request->data and $site after patchEntity:

```
 /src/Controller/Admin/SitesController.php (line 33)

[
'title' => 'test',
'alias' => 'sdfs',
'layout' => 'default',
'sort' => '3',
'sites_meta_data' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'key' => 'keyword',
        'value' => 'test'
    ]
]
]

/src/Controller/Admin/SitesController.php (line 34)

object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

'title' => 'test',
'alias' => 'sdfs',
'layout' => 'default',
'sort' => (int) 3,
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
    'title' => true,
    'alias' => true,
    'layout' => true,
    'sort' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [
    'title' => true,
    'alias' => true,
    'layout' => true,
    'sort' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Sites'

}
```

Also of note. I tried creating the SitesMetaData using `TableRegistry::get('SitesMetaData')->newEntity` with `$this->request->data['sites_meta_data']` and it worked, so I set it to `$site->sites_meta_data[]` and set it as dirty and tried saving and I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, value, created, modified) VALUES (22, 'keyword', 'test', '2015-09-25 18:55:' at line 1
```

In this case, `22` would be the ID of the site after it gets created.

UPDATE:

Despite the docs only mentioning needing to do it when using newEntity() and belongsToMany associations (as far as I can see), I added `sites_meta_data` to the Site entity's `$_accessible` attribute and now I get the above SQL error even while using `$this->Sites->patchEntity($site, $this->request->data ...)` and it now properly builds the SitesMetaData entity.

Comment: Where do the docs mention that? And as far the error goes, `key` is a [**reserved word**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html): **http://stackoverflow.com/a/27859881/1392379**.

Comment: It doesn't mention it explicitly but the only times I've seen it mentioned were under those conditions, like on this page http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields. Anyways, I changed the key and it works properly if you want to make your comment an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as the sql error goes:

`key` is not a valid column name, since it is a sql language construct.

The date field looks wierd `'2015-09-25 18:55:'` and `'test'`  Are you sure you filled it correctly. and the error can stem from the fact it is not a valid value for a datetime column.

i recommend just filling them with chronos entities by using `/Cake/i18n/Time`