# Database Error PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, portal, cakephp-3.x

I created my database tables and bake as usual with CakePHP 3 but when I point my browser to some link it give me this errors:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Users__contact person`, Users.Phoneno AS `Users__Phoneno`, Users.email AS `U' at line 1
>
> If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`, 
        Users.name AS `Users__name`, 
        Users.address AS `Users__address`, 
        Users.contact person AS `Users__contact person`, 
        Users.Phoneno AS `Users__Phoneno`, 
        Users.email AS `Users__email` 
FROM users Users 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

[image: screenshot of the error page for users table]

Comment: Do you really have a space in a column name i.e. `Users.contact person` or should that be an underscore? If its really a space then use `Users.\`contact person\`` i.e. back ticks around the syntactical error

Comment: @RiggsFolly nice job formatting that inline code. I can never get it right :)

Comment: @Phil yea its a beast. You have to use an escape char i.e. "\" on the backticks which you put inside a set of backticks. It can take me ages to get it right sometimes!

Comment: I also have to ask why you would want to create alias names for these column names that have 2 underscores in them? Do you like to make life difficult for yourself?

Comment: The __ is a Cake thing where it is the model__column. This is the way to write native queries and have them return data in the same format as the model.

Comment: the problem is the space in the column name. You can simply avoid using spaces or - if you have to - use `quoteidentifiers => true` in the database settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to safely use reserved SQL names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854333/how-to-safely-use-reserved-sql-names)

Comment: thanks guys and @RiggsFolly nice to have observerd that i have been looking for the reason all day but thank to you the error was from the space in the column contact person instead of contactperson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys and @RiggsFolly nice to have observerd that in the SQL

The error was from the space in the column contact person instead of contactperson in the SQL